# DART type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

At the initialisation of my page, I got the following error :
The relevant error-causing widget was:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'

My program seems to have some difficulties to understand that my id is an int which but be autoincremented, but must be passed in a Map of String.

See the trace :

```
  MaterialApp MaterialApp:file:///D:/Users/lebourgeois/android_studio_projects/tp1/lib/coursSQLite/main.dart:10:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      new Personne.fromMap (package:tp1/coursSQLite/Personne.dart:24:5)
#1      _PersonnePageState.initState (package:tp1/coursSQLite/PersonnePage.dart:33:36)
```

and the dart code associated to the 2 files, Personne and PersonnePage :

```
    import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

const String tablePersonne = 'personne';
const String colonneId = 'id';
const String colonneNom = 'nom';
const String colonnePrenom = 'prenom';
const String colonneAge = 'age';

const String databaseName = 'PersonneDB.db';
const int databaseVersion = 1;

class Personne {
  late int id;
  late String nom;
  late String prenom;
  late String age;

  Personne();

  Personne.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map[colonneId];
    nom = map[colonneNom];
    prenom = map[colonnePrenom];
    age = map[colonneAge];
  }


  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      colonneNom: nom,
      colonnePrenom: prenom,
      colonneAge: age
    };
    if (id != null) {
      map[colonneId] = id;
    }
    return map;
  }
}

class PersonneProvider {
  PersonneProvider._privateConstructor();
  static final PersonneProvider instance = PersonneProvider._privateConstructor();
  late Database _db;
  bool _initialized = false;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (!_initialized) {
      _db = await _initDatabase();
      _initialized = true;
    }
    return _db;
  }

  Future _initDatabase() async {
    try {
      Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, databaseName);
      return await openDatabase(path, version: databaseVersion, onCreate: _open);
    } catch (e) {
      // Gérer l'exception, par exemple:
      print("Erreur lors de l'initialisation de la base de données: $e");
      rethrow; // répéter l'exception pour la gestion au niveau supérieur si nécessaire
    }
  }

  Future _open(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(''' 
     create table $tablePersonne ( 
     $colonneId integer primary key autoincrement, 
     $colonneNom text,
     $colonnePrenom text,
     $colonneAge text) 
     ''');
  }

  Future<int> insert(Personne personne) async {
    Database db = await instance.db;
    int id = await db.insert(tablePersonne, personne.toMap());
    return id;
  }

  Future<Personne?> getPersonne(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.db;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query(tablePersonne,
        columns: [colonneId, colonneNom, colonnePrenom, colonneAge],
        where: '$colonneId = ?',
        whereArgs: [id]);
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      Map<String, dynamic> firstMap = maps.first;
      return Personne.fromMap({
        colonneId: firstMap[colonneId],
        colonneNom: firstMap[colonneNom],
        colonnePrenom: firstMap[colonnePrenom],
        colonneAge: firstMap[colonneAge],
      });
    }
    return null;
  }


  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.db;
    return await db.delete(tablePersonne, where: '$colonneId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future close() async => _db.close();
}
```

And PersonnePage.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'Personne.dart';
import '../CheckboxPage.dart';

void main() => runApp(CheckboxPage());

class PersonnePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SIO',
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: const PersonnePageState(title: 'Cours'),
    );
  }
}

class PersonnePageState extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonnePageState({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _PersonnePageState createState() => _PersonnePageState();
}

class _PersonnePageState extends State<PersonnePageState> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    personneEnregistree = Personne.fromMap(mapPersonne);
    getInstance();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    provider.close();
  }

  final Map<RadioChoix, bool> _mapTransport = {
    RadioChoix.voiture: true,
    RadioChoix.avion: false,
    RadioChoix.bateau: true,
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> mapPersonne = {
    'nom': 'DOE',
    'prenom': 'John',
    'age': '35'
  };
  late Map<String, dynamic> mapPersonneRecuperee;
  Personne personneEnregistree = Personne();
  Personne personneRecuperee = Personne();
  late PersonneProvider provider;

  Future<PersonneProvider> getInstance() async {
    provider = await PersonneProvider.instance;
    return provider;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Icon(
              Icons.account_circle,
              size: 80.0,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            const Text('Données soumises :'),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text(
                        'Nom : ',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${personneEnregistree.toMap()['nom']}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text(
                        'Prénom : ',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${personneEnregistree.toMap()['prenom']}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text(
                        'Age : ',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${personneEnregistree.toMap()['age']}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Text('Données récupérées :'),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
              child: const Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'id : ',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '123',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Nom : ',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'John Doe',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Prénom : ',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Jane Doe',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Age : ',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '30',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Divider(),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: enregistrer,
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  child: Text('Enregistrer'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: recuperer,
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  child: Text('Lire les données'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: supprimer,
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> enregistrer() async {
    int id = await provider.insert(personneEnregistree);
    mapPersonneRecuperee = {'id': id};
    personneRecuperee = Personne.fromMap(mapPersonneRecuperee);
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Enregistrement'),
            content: Text('Les données ont été enregistrées !'),
          );
        });
  }

  Future<void> recuperer() async {
    if (personneRecuperee.toMap()['id'] != 10) {
      personneRecuperee =
      (await provider.getPersonne(personneRecuperee.toMap()['id']))!;
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return const AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Récupération'),
              content: Text('Aucune donnée à récupérer !'),
            );
          });
    }
  }

  Future<void> supprimer() async {
    await provider.delete(personneRecuperee.toMap()['id']);
    setState(() {
      personneRecuperee = Personne();
    });
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Suppression'),
            content: Text('Les données ont été supprimées !'),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Thanks for advance for your efforts and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must mean that the map you provide to `Personne.fromMap` doesn't have a field `id` so it returns null. And this is not allowed if the variable is not nullable. The solution is to either make it nullable or to provide a fallback value, like `0` for example. Furthermore I would suggest to not use `late` variables when not necessary. And there are also some other optimizations you could do.

Here an example using fallback values:

```
class Personne {
  int id = 0;
  String nom = '';
  String prenom = '';
  String age = '';

  Personne();

  Personne.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : id = map[colonneId] ?? 0,
        nom = map[colonneNom] ?? '',
        prenom = map[colonnePrenom] ?? '',
        age = map[colonneAge] ?? '';

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() =>
      {colonneNom: nom, colonnePrenom: prenom, colonneAge: age, colonneId: id};
}
```

Or if you want `null` values to be possible you can make them nullable, like this for example.

```
class Personne {
  int? id;
  String? nom;
  String? prenom;
  String? age;

  Personne();

  Personne.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : id = map[colonneId],
        nom = map[colonneNom],
        prenom = map[colonnePrenom],
        age = map[colonneAge];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        if (nom != null) colonneNom: nom,
        if (prenom != null) colonnePrenom: prenom,
        if (age != null) colonneAge: age,
        if (id != null) colonneId: id
      };
}
```

But keep in mind that if they are nullable that you might need to check for null wherever you are using them.

Or you make some of the variables nullable and some not, depending on what you want

Comment: It's perfect, thanks for your time and your precisions.